# Remove item from an array (useState Hook)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Have a useState hook like so:

```
const [array, updateArray] = useState([])
```

I know you can add items to the array using a spread operator like so.. (where item is whats being added)

```
updateArray(array => [...array, item])
```

how would you remove something from this array? Assuming you have the name of that array item. (remove based off value not index)

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a reference to the exact value that was inserted previously (say it's stored in a variable called `itemToRemove`), you can `.filter` it out:

```
updateArray(array.filter(item => item !== itemToRemove));
```

This works for both primitives and objects, but it's extremely strange to have an exact reference to an object currently in state. For objects, *usually* what you'll do is you'll need to figure out a way to identify the index of the element in state, probably with `findIndex` on a unique property, after which you'd set the new state to the array without that index, something like the following:

```
// say that the array contains objects with a unique 'id' property
// and you need to remove the item with the id of idToRemove
const index = array.findIndex(({ id }) => id === idToRemove);
if (index !== -1) {
  updateArray([
    ...array.slice(0, index),
    ...array.slice(index + 1)
  ]);
}
```