# How to remove an element from array, that array is a state of useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, use-reducer

I have a cart array of carted products. Now i want remove a product using useReducer. I can add products to the cart. But I am not getting the how will i remove that product from the cart. The cart array is a array of object evey obecjt is a product that has name, price, id etc. What will be the logic in this action?

[image]

```
export const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  products: [],
  error: false,
  cart: [],
  wishlist: [],
};

export const productReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.FETCHING_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        error: false,
      };
    case actionTypes.FETCHING_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        products: action.payload,
        error: false,
      };
    case actionTypes.FETCHING_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: true,
      };
    case actionTypes.ADD_TO_CART:
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: [...state.cart, action.payload],
      };
    case actionTypes.ADD_TO_WISHLIST:
      return {
        ...state,
        wishlist: [...state.wishlist, action.payload],
      };
    case actionTypes.REMOVE_FROM_CART:
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: [...state.cart, action.payload],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: can you put an example of a cart item object?

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63948123/remove-item-from-an-array-usestate-hook, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764537/usestate-remove-item-from-array, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57341541/removing-object-from-array-using-hooks-usestate (same problem, different hook).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said the cart items have an `id`. I'm going to assume those are unique.

That being the case, your action should have the `id` of the cart item to remove (`{ type: actionTypes.REMOVE_FROM_CART, id: ___ }`), then the update creates a new array via `filter` that only keeps the cart items that *don't* match the action's `id`:

```
case actionTypes.REMOVE_FROM_CART:
    return {
        ...state,
        cart: state.cart.filter(({id}) => id !== action.id),
    };
```

Or if the action can contain the actual cart item, just compare directly:

```
case actionTypes.REMOVE_FROM_CART:
    return {
        ...state,
        cart: state.cart.filter((item) => item !== action.item),
    };
```